# Querying snowflake table with sqlalchemy adds redundant database name prefix to table names

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using sqlalchemy to query tables in a snowflake db.The sql queries are constructed through code. When it runs something like `conn.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbname.purchase')` it throws the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 002003 (02000): SQL compilation error:
Schema 'DBNAME.DBNAME' does not exist or not authorized.
```

But if I run `conn.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM purchase')` it works just fine. My question is, is this behaviour of prefixing db name configurable because I'd rather not alter the query construction logic. The code is supposed to support quite a few other dialects and snowflake is the only one where this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

DB objects follow three-part naming convention (general rule, not specific to Snowflake Data Cloud):

> [Object Name Resolution](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/name-resolution)
>
> A fully-qualified schema object (table, view, file format etc.) has the form:
>
> ```
> <database_name>.<schema_name>.<object_name>
> ```
>
> However, because this can be tedious to write, **the user is allowed to omit qualifications, from left to right.**

---

With:

```
conn.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbname.purchase')
```

it seeks for schema = dbname/table = purchase.

It should  be provided rather as:

```
# assuming it connects to correct DB at connection level
conn.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema_name.purchase')

# fully-qualified object name
conn.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db_name.schema_name.purchase')
```

Comment: The query construction logic will add the table name as db_name.table_name. The question is if there's a way sqlalchemy will run it as is without trying to replace it with the fully qualified name.

Comment: @JudyTRaj *The query construction logic will add the table name as db_name.table_name.*  Could you provided actual code? Why do  you add `db_name` and not `schema_name`?